# Best way for grouping models by two week periods and tie them to a data entry?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a project that is based on a two week time period. I have a model with a `start_date` and `end_date` as seen below:

```
class CreateNewTimesheet(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(_("Start Date"))
    end_date = models.DateField(_("End Date"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to be able to add another line or something that groups the `start_date` and `end_date`.

```
Dates: 03/06/2024 - 03/16/2024

And group or tie that to "week 1".
```

The purpose behind this is to create a timesheet based on a two week time period. I need to be able to group the timesheets by a two week period and tie them to that specific group. All of the Timesheets need to be stored.

After `start_date` and `end_date` are entered I need them to be tied to week one. I was thinking about adding another line to the `CreateNew` model and then tie that to week one. And then each `start_date` and `end_date` are entered, a new "week" is entered for each new `start_date` and `end_date` is created. Should that be based off of `created_at` entry? Should each week be grouped by a new url?

I am honestly stuck at this point about both grouping by two weeks and then tying to a new week.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a new model `TwoWeekPeriod` to represent the two-week periods.

the week_number is calculated based on the start date and the new `TwoWeekPeriod` is created or retrieved based on the start and end dates.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class TwoWeekPeriod(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(_("Start Date"))
    end_date = models.DateField(_("End Date"))
    week_number = models.IntegerField(_("Week Number"))

class CreateNewTimesheet(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(_("Start Date"))
    end_date = models.DateField(_("End Date"))
    two_week_period = models.ForeignKey(TwoWeekPeriod, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        week_number = (self.start_date - timezone.now().date()).days // 14 + 1
        two_week_period, _ = TwoWeekPeriod.objects.get_or_create(
            start_date=self.start_date,
            end_date=self.end_date,
            defaults={'week_number': week_number}
        )
        self.two_week_period = two_week_period
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**answer to the question on comment**

after defining the `TwoWeekPeriod` model and `CreateNewTimesheet` model as in the above answer get the `TwoWeekPeriod` object for week 1 and then
the timesheets associated with the `TwoWeekPeriod` for week 1

```
week_1_period = TwoWeekPeriod.objects.get(week_number=1)
timesheets_week_1 = CreateNewTimesheet.objects.filter(two_week_period=week_1_period )
```

so `timesheets_week_1` contains all timesheets that belong to week 1

Comment: How would I tie the TwoWeekPeriod model into a timesheet model? For example, if I wanted to get a timesheet from week 1?